# Regex - Works on every Regextester, but not in my vb.net application

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

i got the following regex, which is working on some regex testers out there flawlessly. (for example www.regextester.com)

I want 1 item with "500", 1 with "600" and 1 with "-100".

```
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim regex As New Regex("(\d+)\s\/\s(\d+)\s\((\-?\d+)\)")
    matches = regex.Matches("500 / 600 (-100)")
```

My matches.count is one, with the complete string. Nothing else.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 1 match, with 3 groups. Check `matches(0).Groups(1)` through `matches(0).Groups(3)`

Comment: I think you even have four groups - `matches(0).Groups(0)` would contain the entire match.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Fair enough, there *are* 4 groups. I was just pointing him at the actual information he was after, which is in Groups(1) through (3).

Answer (score 0):

You have one match with three groups.

what result are you expecting?

Comment: Yeah, i thought i would have 1 + 3 Matches... Oh dear. :)